# ASP.net Bin directory - dll loading

Tags: asp.net, dll

I need to use a dll in my asp.net application. How do I load a dll not from a bin directory?

Perhaps I should mention that the application is a mixture of asp code and asp.net code.
so, when I develop it on my machine, I place a dll in the bin directory, but after I move the code to the live environment, I don't want to have a separate bin directory for every piece that's using asp.net.

All I am moving is .aspx and .aspx.cs files. Is there a way to load a dll NOT FROM /bin (specify it with "using" statement)? Looks like it automatically looks in the /bin....

Comment: Why don't you want a bin folder? That's how ASP.NET works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.net app looks in the /bin of the project, and the GAC (Global Assembly Cache) where you put system shared DLL-s.

If your app is one .net app (configured in IIS as one app), but you have aspx files in subfolders, they should see the root /bin folder. i'd stick with keeping dlls in /bin, if that isn't several tenths of bins (which would mean that you have a problem with your app organization).

Answer (score 6):

You can either place the DLL in the bin folder of the root of your application, or install it to the [Global Assembly Cache (GAC) using gacutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c(VS.80).aspx) (which requires the assembly to be strong-named and signed).

I would just keep it in the bin.

Comment: It's worth noting that for assemblies to be loaded into the GAC they need to have a strong name and be signed.

Answer (score 1):

GAC and bin are the only usual options.

You might also be able to [configure your other folder as an additional bin folder](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=4d0ef4fb-f8ae-4355-a658-3c0432c98dbe), but I wouldn't hold my breath — this is from 1.1 and you still need to be within the same vdir as the main application.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the other dll's directories to your path environment variable.  Must restart asp.net process / visual studio for the change to take effect.  Worked for me.

Comment: Can you describe how to add the directories to my path environment variable, or provide a link describing how?

Answer (score 0):

that's the thing: because it's poorly organized (its a mix of asp and asp.net) it's certainly NOT configured properly....I think it's best to have "10 thousands bins" for now.

Thanks guys!

Comment: try to arrange something in the IIS to configure it as one app and/or one virtual directory... play around a bit, maybe you can get it to work with only one /bin